# When I'm trying call the "Initialize pool" method I'm getting the following error in phantom wallet "no changes impacting asset ownership found"

Tags: anchor, rust, react

We used the same code in local net there we got response but in dev net facing issue..below attached the code for your reference.

const initializePool = async () => {

```
const provider = GetProvider(wallet)
console.log("馃殌 ~ getMethods ~ provider:", provider)

let a = JSON.stringify(idle);
let b = JSON.parse(a)

const program = new Program(b, programID, provider)
console.log("馃殌 ~ getMethods ~ program:", program)

const SOLANA_HOST = clusterApiUrl('devnet')
const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection(SOLANA_HOST)
console.log("馃殌 ~ getMethods ~ connection:", connection)

let mint0 = new PublicKey("HMzCURt4JtdnSzF2Mjzj4BhQaYFPjpyhDwjgHZMRLZmh")
let mint1 = new PublicKey("4fwHV1DWySnoXHfrdxUMTxwrjqhbwGXJfRCobWTdeVd9")

let [poolState, poolState_b] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("pool_state"), mint0.toBuffer(), mint1.toBuffer()],
  program.programId,
);

// all derive from state
let [authority, authority_b] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("authority"), poolState.toBuffer()],
  program.programId,
);

let [vault0, vault0_b] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("vault0"), poolState.toBuffer()],
  program.programId,
);
let [vault1, vault1_b] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("vault1"), poolState.toBuffer()],
  program.programId,
);
let [poolMint, poolMint_b] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [Buffer.from("pool_mint"), poolState.toBuffer()],
  program.programId,
);

let fee_numerator = new anchor.BN(1);
let fee_denominator = new anchor.BN(10000);

try {
  let tx = await program.methods.initializePool(fee_numerator, fee_denominator)

    .accounts({
      mint0: mint0,
      mint1: mint1,
      poolAuthority: authority,
      vault0: vault0,
      vault1: vault1,
      poolMint: poolMint,
      poolState: poolState,
      // the rest 
      payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      tokenProgram: token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      associatedTokenProgram: token.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY
    })
    // .signers([publicKey])
    .rpc()



  console.log("tx", tx);

  const transaction: any = new Transaction();
  transaction.add(tx)
  let hxx: any = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
    skipPreflight: true,
  });
  let confirm: any = await connection.confirmTransaction(hxx);
  console.log(confirm, "hxx");

} catch (e) { console.log(e, "error") }
```

};

Comment: is `initialize pool` an instruction to your program? Can you share the code?

Comment: We have attached the code , facing issue in dev net same code we got response in local net...